# Solution Environment

Tags: environments

I want to create solution environment like the image below

[image]

Please help me. Thanking in advanced.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: @Mico Thanks...

Comment: Welcome to the site! :) it's a great community :) to help anyone looking at your question, please could you post what you've tried so far? you'll find a lot of examples on this site that are focused around solutions to exercises. Help us to help you! :) welcome!

Comment: @cmhughes I have written \newtheorem{solution}{Solution:} then I have started \begin{solution} ... \end{solution}. But it gives Solution: 1 .

Comment: Please see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that and update your question accordingly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution [pun intended] that creates a `solution` environment without relying on other packages.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb} % for '\blacksquare' macro
\newenvironment{solution}{%
     \setlength\parindent{0pt}\par\medskip\textbf{Solution}\quad}{%
     \hfill\tiny$\blacksquare$\par\medskip}
     
\begin{document}
\noindent
3. If $G$ is a group such that \dots
\begin{solution}
We have for all $a,b\in G$ \dots

\dots

\medskip
But $b\cdot a=a\cdot b$. \dots 
\end{solution} 
Some text immediately after the \texttt{solution} environment.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Actually I want like Solution: . Also I noticed that there are two much gap between the solution and starting of my answer. I want it to be the normal gap.

Comment: @user454229 - To add a colon, just change `\textbf{Solution}` to `\textbf{Solution}:` in the `\newenvironment` directive.  To reduce the amount of  vertical spacing, just omit one or both `\medskip` directives.

Comment: Hi, actually I am talking about the distance between Solution: --- We have ... in your answer. I want to reduce the distance.

Comment: This space is due to `\quad`. Get rid of it if you don't want this space.

Comment: @SebGlav Thanks...